# Azure DeviceClient does not shut down dotnetty threads on program exit

Tags: c#, .net, azure

When using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient .net framework 4.8 closing out the application leaves multiple Threads running. Specifically DotNetty.Common.dll! DotNetty.Common.Concurrency.SingleThreadEventExecutor.PollTask

Versions 1.34.0 & 1.35.0 of Microsoft.Azure.Devices have this same problem.
Are we using DeviceClient improperly?
Is it a async thing im not understanding?
Am i missing a call to shut it down properly?

From examples online, i shouldn't have to do anything special and it should close it self out.
However it still hangs, currently this is a close implementation. I have yet to make a stand alone, so i havent duplicated this problem with only DeviceClient Code running

When the program exits, is_running gets set, and the program closes down other threads. Eventually we call
Environment.Exit(0);

This should be all the relevant code

```
private void thread_method()
{
    using (var _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connection), TransportType.Mqtt))
    {
        while (is_running)
        {
            var db = new Database(); // roughly an open entity framework connection
            List <class> unprocessed_messages = db.GetUnprocessed();
            List<List<Messages>> processed = breakup_method(unprocessed_messages);
            foreach (var sublist in processed) 
            {

                if (!await SendMessages(sublist , _deviceClient))
                    break;
                // the processed sublist was successful
                db.SaveChanges(); // make sure we dont send again
            }

        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        await _deviceClient.CloseAsync();
    }
}
private async Task<bool> SendMessages(List<Message> messages, DeviceClient _deviceClient)
{
    try
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        await _deviceClient.SendEventBatchAsync(messages, cancellationToken);

        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // logging
    }
    return false;
}
```

Different approach, which doesnt actively send anything.
Just an open , sleep until the program exits, Then close,
All in a using statement.
8 threads are still running the PollTask, and in the amount of time it took to setup everything above, was the time i was waiting for them to close. Which was at least 5 minutes.

```
private void thread_method()
{   
   using (var _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connection), TransportType.Mqtt))
    {
       await _deviceClient.OpenAsync();
       while (is_running) Thread.Sleep(500);
       await _deviceClient.CloseAsync();
    }

}
```

Last update, stand alone console app.
100% not my problem.

```
// Repost just in case
class Program
{
private static string _connection_string = $"HostName={url};DeviceId={the_id};SharedAccesskey={key}";// fill your in
    public static bool is_running = false;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        is_running = true;
        new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(thread_method)).Start();
        Console.WriteLine("enter to exit");
        String line = Console.ReadLine();
        is_running = false;
    }
    public static async void thread_method()
    {
        using (var _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_connection_string, TransportType.Mqtt))
        {
            await _deviceClient.OpenAsync();
            while (is_running) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            await _deviceClient.CloseAsync();
        }
        }
}
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24550
Bumped to the proper location
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/2194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24550
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/2194

Not a configuration issue, a 'dot netty' bug was hanging.
The fix, get a newer azure version  Microsoft.Azure.Devices  > 1.35.0